# Using Combine to validate and submit form in UIKit

Tags: swift, mvvm, combine

I am working on a form build with Storyboard(UIKit). I have 4 input fields and when it is valid I will submit the data to a UI and show response on UI. I have created a ViewModel and added the validation code there. Following is my validation code:

```
@Published public var firstName = ""
    @Published public var lastName = ""
    @Published public var phoneNumber = ""
    @Published public var emailAddress = ""    
var isFirstNameValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        $firstName
            .map { name in
                return name.count >= 3
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    var isLastNameValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        $lastName
            .map { name in
                return name.count >= 3
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    var isUserEmailValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
          $emailAddress
              .map { email in
                  let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}")
                  return emailPredicate.evaluate(with: email)
              }
              .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      
      var isPhoneNumberValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
          $phoneNumber
              .map { phoneNumber in
                  return phoneNumber.count >= 8
              }
              .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
    
    public func isValidForm(firstName: String, lastName: String, phoneNum: String, emailAddress: String, isConsent: Bool) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNum
        self.emailAddress = emailAddress
        
        return Publishers.CombineLatest4(
          isFirstNameValidPublisher,
          isLastNameValidPublisher,
          isUserEmailValidPublisher,
          isPhoneNumberValidPublisher)
            .map { isFirstNameValid, isLastNameValid, isPhoneNumberValid, isEmailValid in
                return isFirstNameValid && isLastNameValid && isPhoneNumberValid && isEmailValid && isConsent
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

I Am trying to use this on submit button click in my ViewController as following:

```
cancellable = dependencies.leadConsumptionUseCase.isValidForm(firstName: firstNameTextView.text, lastName: lastNameTextView.text, phoneNum: phoneNumberTextView.text, emailAddress: emailTextView.text, isConsent: true).collect().sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print("completed")
        print(completion)
    }, receiveValue: { res in
        print("result")
        print(res)
    })
```

I am able to validate the fields in ViewModel but somehow I am not getting any response in my ViewController.
Also I am not sure how and where should I add the api call. I have already created another service class where I have an api call that will return the response as AnyCancellable.
Most of the related examples are with SwiftUI but I am not using SwiftUI.

**Edit:**
After removing collect from my isValidForm function call I am able to get the response but now it is coming multiple times. As a result of that my api call is executing multiple time.

Comment: `CombineLatest` will only fire after all four of the other publishers publish a value.  Are all four of your publishers invoked before you try to see output from `isValidForm`?  What happens if you add a "`.print()` operator in each of your publishers, and then in the `isValidForm` publisher?

Comment: Hi @ScottThompson yes all four of these should be valid. All of these fields are essential and user must enter these fields before we can submit to server

Answer (score 2):

There is a working example of how one might use this code below.

`isValidForm()` now just returns the publisher, it doesn't take in values.  The values you are trying to validate are coming in through the four streams that you've constructed.

As I suggested, I've included `.print` operators so that you can see, in the debug output, how each stream participates in the validation.

In the main body of the playground I send values into the four streams one at a time. As each value is sent, the `isValidForm()` publisher emits a `false` value until all the fields have been sent.  It then emits a `true` letting you know that all four fields have valid values.

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class Form : ObservableObject {
    @Published public var firstName = ""
    @Published public var lastName = ""
    @Published public var phoneNumber = ""
    @Published public var emailAddress = ""

    var isFirstNameValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
            $firstName
                .map { name in
                    return name.count >= 3
                }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        var isLastNameValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
            $lastName
                .map { name in
                    return name.count >= 3
                }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        var isUserEmailValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
              $emailAddress
                  .map { email in
                      let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}")
                      return emailPredicate.evaluate(with: email)
                  }
                  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
          }
          
          var isPhoneNumberValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
              $phoneNumber
                  .map { phoneNumber in
                      return phoneNumber.count >= 8
                  }
                  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
          }
        
        public func isValidForm() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
            return Publishers.CombineLatest4(
                isFirstNameValidPublisher.print("first name"),
              isLastNameValidPublisher.print("last name"),
              isUserEmailValidPublisher.print("email"),
              isPhoneNumberValidPublisher.print("phone"))
                .map { isFirstNameValid, isLastNameValid, isPhoneNumberValid, isEmailValid in
                    return isFirstNameValid && isLastNameValid && isPhoneNumberValid && isEmailValid
                }
                .print("isValidForm")
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
}

let form = Form()
let validWatcher = form.isValidForm().sink { isValid in
    print("Is the form valid?: \(isValid)")
}
form.firstName = "Scott"
form.lastName = "Thompson"
form.phoneNumber = "(123) 555-1234}"
form.emailAddress = "someemail@somefakeplacename.com"
```